# Finding most common language per country, using subquery - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I am brand new to SQL, as I am taking an introductory course. I've read through my text book, and looked at as much material online as I can find...

I have a table, [Language], which includes columns Language.Country, Language.Name and Language.Percentage. 
This is a list of all countries, the languages spoken in them, and the percentage of speakers which speak each language.

I have been tasked with displaying the most common language per country using a subquery.

One thing I have tried:

```
SELECT Country, MAX(Percentage) AS Percentage
FROM Language
GROUP BY Country;
```

Which does return the correct answer, but I cannot display the name of the language which corresponds with that Percentage, and I cannot see how I would use a subquery to get the correct results. This is driving me a little mad, tbh.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?

Comment: @HABO Assuming I had any, which would by necessity be a 50/50 split, how could I force the query to display both? I've ran the query that Andrey Nikolov helpfully provided, and I do indeed see one country with "50" listed under percentage, but only one row. How would I display the second language as Well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub-query should return the most common language in the corresponding country, i.e. to return the first row order by percentage descending.

```
SELECT
    Country
    , MAX(Percentage) AS Percentage
    , (select top 1 Name from Language i where i.Country = l.Country order by Percentage desc) as MostCommonLanguage
FROM Language l
GROUP BY Country;
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes much more sense now! You see, I didn't realize that I could use a subquery in that way, i.e. as part of the columns that I want to retrieve listed after the SELECT clause, and then given a name. I was under the impression that subqueries needed to come after WHERE clauses. Neither my instructor nor my text book made that clear.

Comment: If I may ask an additional question, because it will help me understand what this query is doing: Is this an example of a correlated subquery? In other words, is the subquery selecting the top 1 result from a list of all languages ordered by percentage descending for each unique "Country" value that the outer query evaluates? Uh, if that makes sense?

Comment: Correlated sub-query means that it depends on the outer query. In this case for each row you return value depending on the country of the outer query. It won't be correlated, if there is no dependency between both queries, e.g. the sub-query returns the most common language in the whole world (i.e. omitting the where clause of the sub-query) and it will return the same value for every row.

Comment: So, I'm sorry, just to clarify...This is a correlated subquery? Or is it not?

Comment: `(select top 1 Name from Language i where i.Country = l.Country order by Percentage desc) as MostCommonLanguage` is a correlated sub-query, because it filters the result depending on the value of Country field from the outer query. So yes, it is.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much, you've been a tremendous help. I know I may be a bit slow with this, but I am very new and still trying to wrap my head around what my code is doing. I always feel uncomfortable when my code works, but my brain can't figure out WHY it works, exactly :-).